# rust how to have multiple mutable references to a stack allocated object?

Tags: c, pointers, rust, stack

Let us say we have this C code:

```c
typedef struct A { int i; } A;
typedef struct B { A* a; } B;
typedef struct C { A* a; } C;

int main(void)
{
  A a = { .i = 42 };
  B b = { .a = &a };
  C c = { .a = &a };
}
```

In this scenario A is stack allocated, B and C point to the stack allocated memory where A lives.

I need to do exactly the same thing in rust but every time I try to create mutliple mutable references it complaints.

It's a little frustrating having to fight the language to accomplish something so basic.

Comment: This is against the main rule of borrow-checking: an exclusive (mutable) reference is actually exclusive. Dereferencing a null or uninitialised pointer is something basic too, but Rust is designed in order to prevent this.

Comment: Rust advertises itself as a low level system's language. Safety guarantees as default are great, but sometimes, due to hardware access or interfacing with unsafe C libraries it is no possible to maintain all safety guarantees.

This is one such case and I relly need to accomplish this.

Comment: In this case, use `*mut A`  in your structures (instead of `&mut A`) and `unsafe` every time you use these pointers, but it's risky.

Comment: In this case I am touching the hardware left and right, safety is already implicitly out the window. Thank you for the suggestion, I will try it out.

Comment: "stack allocated" is not a thing

Comment: Edit the wikipedia page then:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation

Comment: @Makogan first "This article has multiple issues." then your code snipped was not valid C code finally I'm a C expert and "stack" word is never ever used in the +700 pages of C ISO. So "stack allocated" is not a thing in C.

Comment: @Stargateur Not trying to pick a fight! This 1981 article by Dennis Ritchie (and others) makes liberal use of the term "stack"... https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/clcs.html

Comment: @Fe2O3 I didn't want to say stack is not a thing I said stack is not a thing in this context. 99% of Implementation of C use a stack. [alloca](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html) is a not standard at all but have a stack allocated concept but again that IMPLEMENTATION feature. C itself have no concept of stack so can't have stack allocated thing. Then the very notion of use the stack to allocate is broken since forever, it's have create a lot of bug and problem and is very much buried for a reason. Your article is about implementation of C not C.

Comment: @Finomnis my point is that OP doesn't look to understand that stack is not a theoretical concept of C language, mean that the premise are wrong and the very core of the question is wrong, "a stack allocated object" => not a thing then "rust how to have multiple mutable references to" => the core rule of Rust https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html?highlight=mut#the-rules-of-references. That mean answer would need to explain Rust and C, that way too broad.

Comment: @Stargateur then replace his "stack allocated" with "non-boxed" or "function-local". My point is that the intention of his question has nothing with your discussion. He is trying to apply concepts known from C to Rust and gets problems with the borrow checker, which is a frustrating problem for Rust beginners. A theoretical discussion about the meaning of "stack" will not help him in any way.

Answer (score 8):

> It's a little frustrating having to fight the language to accomplish something so basic.

It's not as basic as you think. Rust's main premise is to have zero undefined behaviour, and it's almost impossible to have two mutable references simultaneously while upholding that guarantee. How would you make sure that through the means of multithreading you don't accidentally get a race condition? This already is undefined behaviour that might be exploitable for malicious means.

Learning Rust is not easy, and it is especially hard if you come from a different language, as many programming paradigms simply don't work in Rust. But I can assure you that once you understand how to structure code differently, it will actually become a positive thing, because Rust forces programmers to distance themselves from questionable patterns, or patterns that seem fine but need a second glance to understand what is actually wrong with them. C/C++ bugs are usually very subtle and caused by some weird cornercase, and after programming in Rust for a while, it is incredibly rewarding to have the assurance that those corner cases simply don't exist.

But back to your problem.

There are two language concepts here that need to be combined to achieve what you are trying to do.

For once, the borrow checker forces you to have only one mutable reference to a specific piece of data at once. That means, if you definitely want to modify it from multiple places, you will **have** to utilize a concept called [interior mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html). Depending on your usecase, there are several ways to create interior mutability:

- [`Cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html) - single-threaded, for primitive types that can be replaced by being copied. This is a zero-cost abstraction.
- [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html) - single-threaded, for more complex types that require a mutable reference instead of being updatable by replacement. Minimal overhead to check if it is already borrowed.
- [`Atomic`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/) - multi-threaded, for primitive types. In most cases zero-cost abstractions (on x86-64 everything up to u64/i64 is already atomic out of the box, zero overhead required)
- [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html) - like `RefCell`, but for multiple threads. Larger overhead due to active internal lock management.

So depending on your usecase, you need to choose the right one. In your case, if your data is really an `int`, I'd go with a `Cell` or an `Atomic`.

Second, there is the problem of how to get multiple (immutable) references to your object in the first place.

Right away, I would like to tell you: Do **not** use raw pointers prematurely. Raw pointers and `unsafe` bypass the borrow checker and make Rust as a language pointless. 99.9% of problems work great and performant without using raw pointers, so only use them in circumstances where absolutely no alternative exists.

That said, there are three general ways to share data:

- [`&A`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html) - Normal reference. While the reference exists, the referenced object cannot be moved or deleted. So this is probably not what you want.
- [`Rc<A>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-04-rc.html) - Single threaded reference counter. Very lightweight, so don't worry about overhead. Accessing the data is a zero-cost abstraction, additional cost only arises when you copy/delete the actual `Rc` object. Moving the `Rc` object *should* theoretically be free as this doesn't change the reference count.
- [`Arc<A>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html) - Multi threaded reference counter. Like `Rc`, the actual access is zero-cost, but the cost of copying/deleting the `Arc` object itself is minimally higher than `Rc`. Moving the `Arc` object *should* theoretically be free as this doesn't change the reference count.

So assuming that you have a single threaded program and the problem is exactly as you layed it out, I'd do:

```
use std::{cell::Cell, rc::Rc};

struct A {
    i: Cell<i32>,
}
struct B {
    a: Rc<A>,
}
struct C {
    a: Rc<A>,
}

fn main() {
    let a = Rc::new(A { i: Cell::new(42) });
    let b = B { a: Rc::clone(&a) };
    let c = C { a: Rc::clone(&a) };

    b.a.i.set(69);
    c.a.i.set(c.a.i.get() + 2);
    println!("{}", a.i.get());
}
```

```
71
```

But of course all the other combinations, like `Rc` + `Atomic`, `Arc` + `Atomic`, `Arc` + `Mutex` etc are also viable. It depends on your usecase.

If your `b` and `c` objects provably live shorter than `a` (meaning, if they only exist for a couple of lines of code and don't get moved anywhere else) then of course use a reference instead of `Rc`. The biggest performance difference between `Rc` and a direct reference is that the object inside of an `Rc` lives on the heap, not on the stack, so it's the equivalent of calling `new`/`delete` once in C++.

So, for reference, if your data sharing allows the object to live on the stack, like in our example, then the code would look like this:

```
use std::cell::Cell;

struct A {
    i: Cell<i32>,
}
struct B<'a> {
    a: &'a A,
}
struct C<'a> {
    a: &'a A,
}

fn main() {
    let a = A { i: Cell::new(42) };
    let b = B { a: &a };
    let c = C { a: &a };

    b.a.i.set(69);
    c.a.i.set(c.a.i.get() + 2);
    println!("{}", a.i.get());
}
```

```
71
```

Note that the reference is zero-cost and `Cell` is also zero-cost, so this code will perform 100% identical to as if you had used raw pointers; with the difference that the borrow checker can now prove that this will not cause undefined behaviour.

To demonstrate just **how** zero-cost this is, look at the [assembly output of the example above](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/PsM91rxn8).
The compiler managed to optimize the entire code to:

```
fn main() {
    println!("{}", 71);
}
```

Be aware that in your C example, nothing would prevent you from copying the `b` object somewhere else while `a` gets out of scope and gets destroyed. This would cause undefined behavior and will get prevented by the borrow checker in Rust, which is the reason the structs `B` and `C` carry the lifetime `'a` to track the fact that they borrow an `A`.

Lastly, I would like to talk about `unsafe` code. Yes, if you interface with `C` or write low-level drivers that require direct memory access, `unsafe` is absolutely important to have. That said, it's important that you understand how to deal with `unsafe` in order to still keep up Rusts safety guarantees. Otherwise, there really isn't any point in using Rust. Don't just use `unsafe` out of convenience to simply overrule the borrow checker, but instead make sure that the resulting `unsafe` usage is **sound**. Please read [this article about soundness](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html) before you use the `unsafe` keyword.

I hope this managed to get you a glimpse of what kind of thinking is required for programming in Rust, and hope it did not intimidate you too much. Give it a chance; while having a fairly steep learning curve, especially for programmers with strong prior knowledge in other languages, it can be very rewarding.

Answer (score 3):

This may not apply to your specific situation as indicated in the comments, but the *general* way to solve this in Rust is with a [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html).  This type allows you to obtain a `&mut T` from a `&RefCell<T>`.  For example:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;

struct A(pub RefCell<i32>);
struct B<'a>(pub &'a RefCell<i32>);

fn main() {
    let a = A(RefCell::new(0));
    let b = B(&a.0);
    let c = B(&a.0);
    
    *b.0.borrow_mut() = 1;
    println!("{}", c.0.borrow());
    
    *c.0.borrow_mut() = 2;
    println!("{}", b.0.borrow());
}
```

Note that `RefCell` has overhead in the form of a borrow count, required to enforce Rust's aliasing rules at runtime (it will panic if a mutable borrow exists concurrently with any other borrow).

If the underlying type is `Copy` and you don't need references to the inner value then you can use `Cell`, which does not have any runtime overhead, as each operation fully retrieves or replaces the contained value:

```
use std::cell::Cell;

struct A(pub Cell<i32>);
struct B<'a>(pub &'a Cell<i32>);

fn main() {
    let a = A(Cell::new(0));
    let b = B(&a.0);
    let c = B(&a.0);
    
    b.0.set(1);
    println!("{}", c.0.get());
    
    c.0.set(2);
    println!("{}", b.0.get());
}
```

Note that `Cell` is [`#[repr(transparent)]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/other-reprs.html#reprtransparent) which is particularly useful in systems programming as it permits some types of zero-cost transmuting between different types.

Comment: The solution to this problem was `*mut` without a doubt. The additional overhead is not worth the safety guarantees for my purposes.

Comment: @Makogan `Cell` has no such overhead.

Comment: From the answer: 
> Note that RefCell has overhead in the form of a borrow count

Comment: @Makogan `Cell` and `RefCell` are different. Don't be so hasty to jump into unsafe Rust if you're coming from C. A lot of "basic" techniques in C are better written in Rust using other techniques.

Comment: @Makogan `Cell` is like `RefCell` in that it offers interior mutability, but the mechanism is different. With `Cell` you cannot get a reference to the inner value at all; there is no borrowing. Instead, you can only fetch, store, or swap. The pointer approach with `i32` and `*mut i32` maps exactly onto `Cell<i32>` and `&Cell<i32>` respectively, and the runtime performance characteristics should be identical, except `Cell` doesn't require `unsafe`.

Comment: @Makogan I'll have to tell you that if you think of those "safety guarantees" as "worthless", then Rust might be the wrong language for you. Rusts main purpose is to uphold those safety guarantees, while being as performant as possible. And the cost of those safety guarantees is actually very small, many of them being zero-cost abstractions. So I wouldn't jump to the conclusion that "the additional overhead is not worth it" before actually benchmarking it. I think your conclusion here is premature.

Comment: @Makogan Even if he says "overhead", it's quite small. Look at the assembly: [Direct](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/81TfWzhGq) vs [Cell](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/aqjznx53x) vs [RefCell](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/eGsd3bb3q)