# How to check the contents of stdout without triggering a move error?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

In the following code, I write some text to `stdout`:

```
use std::{
    io::Write,
    sync::{Arc, Mutex},
};

pub struct CmdRunner {}

impl CmdRunner {
    pub fn run<W: Write + Send + 'static>(&mut self, stdout_mutex: Arc<Mutex<Option<W>>>) {
        // Code that runs the command

        let stdout_clone = Arc::clone(&stdout_mutex);

        std::thread::spawn(move || {
            // This is wrapped in code that listens to Ctrl + C (in raw mode)

            let stdout_clone = Arc::clone(&stdout_mutex);
            let mut stdout_lock = stdout_clone.lock().unwrap();

            stdout_lock.take();
        });

        let mut stdout_lock = stdout_clone.lock().unwrap();
        let stdout = stdout_lock.as_mut().unwrap();

        write!(stdout, "Command executed successfully!\r\n").unwrap();
    }
}

fn handle_cmd_input<T: Write>(stdout: &mut T) {
    write!(stdout, "Input handled!\r\n").unwrap();
}

fn handle_cmd_run<T: Write + std::marker::Send + 'static>(mut stdout: T) {
    handle_cmd_input(&mut stdout);

    let mut cmd_runner = CmdRunner {};
    let stdout_mutex = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Some(stdout)));   

    cmd_runner.run(stdout_mutex);
}

fn main() {
    let stdout = Vec::new();

    handle_cmd_run(stdout);

    let stdout_string = String::from_utf8_lossy(&stdout);
    println!("stdout: {}", stdout_string);
}
```

As you can see, I tried to print `stdout`, but that produces an error:

```
44 |     let stdout = Vec::new();
   |         ------ move occurs because `stdout` has type `Vec<u8>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
45 |
46 |     handle_cmd_run(stdout);
   |                    ------ value moved here
47 |
48 |     let stdout_string = String::from_utf8_lossy(&stdout);
   |                                                 ^^^^^^^ value borrowed here after move
```

The compiler suggests I write:

```
46 |     handle_cmd_run(stdout.clone());
   |                          ++++++++
```

But if I do that, `write!` will write to the cloned `stdout`, not to the original `stdout`.

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4d2b494d2a3c13d173a9f782157202dd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is ownership; the compiler is correct to complain about your code.

You have to be aware during programming where a variable lives. Rust `Arc<Mutex>`es work different than C/C++; they don't live besides the variable, but wrap **around** it. This means that once you move a variable inside of an `Arc<Mutex>`, you will never be able to get it back out.

With that knowledge it makes sense why the compiler complains about `String::from_utf8_lossy(&stdout);` - the `stdout` variable now lives inside of the mutex, and the original `stdout` variable no longer exists.

There are several ways to solve this:

- Create the `Arc<Mutex>` earlier and use it for `String::from_utf8_lossy`.
- Don't create an `Arc<Mutex>` at all, but instead return the `stdout` data from your function
- Use normal `&mut` references instead of the whole `Arc<Mutex>` shenanigans - this will require [scoped threads](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/fn.scope.html).

Which one you choose depends on your usecase, of course.

From the small example you provide, I would personally go with scoped threads:

```rust
use std::io::Write;

pub struct CmdRunner {}

impl CmdRunner {
    pub fn run<W: Write + Send>(&mut self, stdout: &mut W) {
        // Code that runs the command

        std::thread::scope(|s| {
            s.spawn(|| {
                // This is wrapped in code that listens to Ctrl + C (in raw mode)
                write!(stdout, "Command output: 42\r\n").unwrap();
            });
        });

        write!(stdout, "Command executed successfully!\r\n").unwrap();
    }
}

fn handle_cmd_input<T: Write>(stdout: &mut T) {
    write!(stdout, "Input handled!\r\n").unwrap();
}

fn handle_cmd_run<T: Write + Send>(stdout: &mut T) {
    handle_cmd_input(stdout);

    let mut cmd_runner = CmdRunner {};

    cmd_runner.run(stdout);
}

fn main() {
    let mut stdout = Vec::new();

    handle_cmd_run(&mut stdout);

    let stdout_string = String::from_utf8_lossy(&stdout);
    println!("stdout: {}", stdout_string);
}
```

```
stdout: Input handled!
Command output: 42
Command executed successfully!
```

The reason this works is because `Arc<Mutex>` for threads is **not** required because of the nature of multithreading; it is required because threads spawned by `std::thread::spawn` have an open-ended lifetime that is disconnected from their spawning scope. By spawning it through `std::thread::scope` the thread's lifetime gets connected to the parent scope, and normal references can be used from within. Also note that the `move` got removed from the closure to prevent moving the `stdout` variable into the thread.

**Disclaimer:** I assumed that you forgot to `join` the thread, otherwise your entire code wouldn't make much sense. Be aware that the `std::thread::scope` automatically joins at the end, so your parent thread will be blocked until the thread is done, and `"Command executed successfully!"` will only get added to `stdout` once the thread has exited. If that is not the behavior you desire then you have to go a different path.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. So if I don't want to block the parent thread while the spawned thread is running, I can't use `scope`? For example, if I want to listen to Ctrl + C in the spawned thread to stop the execution of a command in the parent thread?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you are talking about. I think your [MRE] does not represent your problem well then ... where exactly would you run code in the parent? Is it at the place where it says `Code that runs the command`? If yes, how would you ever even get to the `spawn` while the command runs? Or with other words, why do you even need a thread?

Comment: Sorry, I should have given you an example. The `run()` function would look like this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3298b601ed4e7e781893b3e5d218f138. `spawned_thread` is there to listen to Ctrl + C and stop the executing command (which is in the parent thread).

Comment: @alexchenco I'm still unsure what you are trying to achieve here, but you can spawn multiple threads inside of `scope` and then they will all be joined at the end. Or if order matters, you can manually join some of them inside of the `scope`.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice. I'll try that out. So `scope` can basically solve most of the problems that Mutex solves? At least in cases like this one?

Comment: @alexchenco The big detail here that we didn't talk about yet is that there is only **one single point of mutation**. We only have one `&mut` reference and no other references. That's the situation `scope` solves. `Mutex`, on the other hand, is a lot more powerful - it converts a `&` reference to a `&mut` one, meaning many threads can share one resource. What scope then replaces is the `Arc` part - you can have a `Mutex` and share it via `&` and `scope` to many threads. No `Arc` required. I know this was a lot of information very quickly, but I hope it made some sort of sense.

Comment: @alexchenco For more information, I actually wrote a couple of other answers that go into more detail about data sharing and interior mutability. Like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73340544/rust-how-to-have-multiple-mutable-references-to-a-stack-allocated-object/73344290#73344290,

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information! I'll check your other answers.

Comment: You're right, the parent thread will be blocked unless I press CTRL + C (in the original code). I want the parent thread to exit when the command is finished (without having to wait for the scoped thread to exit). What other path do you suggest? This is the original code: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7258aa401a99cb4d5db4967240b1db7b

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253756/discussion-between-finomnis-and-alexchenco).